# Force rebuild of a minion's state?

Tags: saltstack

### TL;DR

I have begun controlling all my virtual machines using Saltstack. I have set up two separate environments, `init` and `base`, for installing the minion on a freshly deployed VM and ongoing configuration management, respectively. Having successfully deployed a minion, it adheres to the states from BOTH environments! I don't want that. It should only be managed according to the `base` environment.

Why does it use both environments and how do I force it to not care about the `init` environment anymore, after initial deployment?

---

Having deployed a new VM I use `salt-ssh` to set up repositories, install the salt minion and fire it up. After that I use `salt` to manage my VMs. So for every new VM I do (once)

```
salt-ssh -i 'anewhost' state.apply
```

and after that I do/cron does

```
salt '*' state.apply
```

The configuration of my file roots are the only content of my master's configuration file:

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt/base
  init:
    - /srv/salt/init
```

To make a VM a minion I use a roster file. `/etc/salt/roster`, where every block looks like this:

```
anewhost:
  host: anewhost.mydomain.tld
  user: root
  passwd: rootpw
  minion_opts:
    environment: init
```

The idea is

- when I do `state.apply` using `salt-ssh`, the state is constructed starting at `/srv/salt/init/top.sls`
- when I do `state.apply` using `salt`, the state is constructed starting at `/srv/salt/base/top.sls`

What happens is, that `salt-ssh` behaves exactly like expected, but `salt` creates some unified abomination that actually contains both states, described by `init` and `base`.

Apparently `salt` remembers the `init` environment and pulls it in, no matter what I do. How do I make it forget about the `init` environment?

### Edit: Quickfix

I fixed it by augmenting my `init` states to append `environment: base` to `/etc/salt/minion`. This actually makes the minion ignore the `init` environment. But why did it honor it in the first place? Isn't the idea behind environments to make salt do different things?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably not really answer your question, anyway in my setup I just use the base environment and I do the salt bootstrap using [saltify](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/cloud/saltify.html).
This way you don't need the `init` environment at all